# Fetching param.id data from front to backend - React / Node / Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ajax, express, parameters

I am trying to return a user list on a component from my backend and I am having trouble passing my userID param back. I am using useEffect to pull the data from Redux then call an action on the component with what I think is the declared param. The correct userID is being passed correctly as far as I can see however I think the error is occuring when the route is passed the param.

In my action how should I pass the param of the userID that I want to get the data for? I have console.log the param.id/param.userID/userID etc. In the component I have the user.userID (from useSelector) however in the action folder I don't know how to pass it to the backend.

**Also** in the backend do I always have to set my params as id? can these have the same name as the value on the front-end such as 'userID'? I can only seem to get the backend Postman calls working with :id.

[image: ![image|690x249](upload://acH5vA0ni6ClNNGOWwGE7mHhfYH.png)]

**component**

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);

    const [userDiveLog, setUserDiveLog] = useState({
        user: [],
        userDiveLogList: [],

        expanded: false
    })

    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUserDiveLog(user.userID));
    }, []);
```

**action**

```
// pulls the user dive log
export function fetchUserDiveLog(params, credentials, diveLogUserList){
    return function(dispatch){
        return axios.get("http://localhost:5002/api/divelog/userdiveloglist/" + params.userID)
            .then(({data}) => {
                dispatch(userDiveLogList(data));
            });
    };
}
```

**Backend**

**route**

```
//  return an individual dive log
    app.get('/api/divelog/userdiveloglist/:userID', controller.userDiveLog);
```

**controller**

```
exports.userDiveLog = (req, res, params, userID) => {

    try {
        const userID = req.params.userID

        diveLog.findAll({
            include: {all: true},
            where: {diverUserNumber: userID}
        })
            .then(diveLog => {
                const userDiveLogList = [];
                for (i = 0; i < diveLog.length; i++) {
                    userDiveLogList.push(diveLog[i].dataValues);
                }
                if (!userDiveLogList) {
                    return res.status(404).send({message: "No dive logs belonging to this user"});
                }
                res.status(200).send({
                    data: userDiveLogList
                })
            })
    } catch(err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving dive log belonging to user id= " + id
            });
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Frontend

You're passing the user id (`user.userID` - a string) to the `fetchUserDiveLog` function but you're treating it like a params object with the `userID` property inside the function. `params.userID` returns `undefined` since `params` is a string (it holds the user id). Rename `params` to `userId` and add it to the URL.

You can also remove the `credentials` and `diveLogUserList` arguments from the `fetchUserDiveLog` function since they aren't used.

```js
export function fetchUserDiveLog(userId) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5002/api/divelog/userdiveloglist/${userId}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        dispatch(userDiveLogList(data))
      })
  }
}
```

Btw, you shouldn't hardcode the API URL. Use environment variables. If you're using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), you can [add environment variables prefixed with `REACT_APP_` to `.env`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) or you can use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) if you have a custom Webpack setup.

#### Backend

There are a few issues with the backend code.

1. The `userDiveLog` function receives the `next` function as the third argument but it is named `params` which is confusing. Since you don't need the `next` function in the request handler, you should remove the `params` and `userID` arguments from the function. You can get access to `userID` from the `req.params` object which you're doing correctly.

```
exports.userDiveLog = (req, res) => {
  // ...
}
```

2. The `if (!userDiveLogList)` condition will never be true since `userDiveLogList` is an array which is truthy in JavaScript. You can actually remove the `if` block. A response of `{ data: [] }` will be sent if the user doesn't have any `Divelog`s which is perfectly okay. You can also omit the `status(200)` call since the status is automatically set to `200`. And you can refactor the code by using object destructuring and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the divelogs.

```js
const { userID } = req.params

const diveLogs = await diveLog.findAll({
  include: { all: true },
  where: { diverUserNumber: userID },
})

const data = diveLogs.map((log) => log.dataValues)
res.send({ data })
```

3. The `catch` block references the variable `id` which isn't defined anywhere. It should be `userID` instead.

The whole code using `async/await`:

```
exports.userDiveLog = async (req, res) => {
  const { userID } = req.params
  try {
    const diveLogs = await diveLog.findAll({
      include: { all: true },
      where: { diverUserNumber: userID },
    })
    const data = diveLogs.map((log) => log.dataValues)
    res.send({ data })
  } catch () {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: `Error retrieving dive log belonging to user id= ${userID}`,
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have identified two questions after reading the description and I am going to answer each of those at a time.

### Do I have to set the query parameter as Id?

No, there are no restrictions on the name of query parameter. You can literally name it as "something".
That said, there are some conventions and those dictate that you need to name the parameter to something that is appropriate.

### How do I pass `userId` to my Action Creator?

First of all check the Function that is wrapping your Thunk. It expects 3 parameters: `params` (POORLY NAMED), `credentials` and `diveLogUserList`.
Where as, it is being dispatched with only 1 argument: `userID`.

Reconfigure this Wrapper Function to just receive the userID as an argument (and send credentials, diveUserList as an extra argument to the Thunk and not the wrapper function; This depends upon the functionality that you desire which is not properly understandable using the Description that you have provided).

After you reconfigured the wrapper function, you will dispatch the same like this:
`fetchUserDiveLog(userID)`.

### The Function handling your Route is incorrect

If I am not mistaken, `controller.userDiveLog` should only receive 3 arguments yet, you have defined your handler with 4 parameters.

The arguments that your handler should expect are: `request`, `response` and `next`.

The User ID that your handler expects will be a query parameter and will be accessible using: `request.params.userID`.

There is no need to expect userID as an argument to your handler.

### Additional Information

I recommend going through these to get a better explanation and along with that, I recommend use of `console.log` as a method to debug the code. It will help you identify problems such as:

- **How many arguments is this function receiving?**
- **What is the type of the argument received?**
- And much more

#### References

- [Route Function or Route Handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes#route_functions)
- [Route Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes#route_parameters)
- [Sending Extra Argument to a Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument)